# How to do cleanup before an Outlook add-in is removed?

Tags: outlook-addin

I am developing an add-in for Outlook.
I am setting some variables in RoamingSettings which I want to remove before the add-in is removed.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Which roaming settings? Local machine? Or an Outlook mailbox (e.g. PR_ROAMING_XML property)?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Outlook mailbox

Answer (score 0):

You can of course start Outlook from your installer and remove the data, but that would be a horrible idea. What if the user will reinstall your app later? Most likely you won't be able to start Outlook if it is already running since the installer user and security context is different from the identity of the user used to run Outlook.